# Tuning cars for drag racing in Forza 3?

Tags: forza-motorsport-3

It seems to me that tuning cars for the standard race tracks in Forza is relatively straightforward: Depending on your needs and your base car, optimize for various parameters. (For me, weight reduction is always a favorite -- relatively cheap and massive performance gains.)

But when dealing with drag racing, it's a whole different ballgame. For one, most drag racing fans who've played Forza (myself included) tend to be a bit disillusioned with the drag mode. It seems like AWD always has a crazy advantage. It seems like there's no way to build an American muscle car (Buick GNX, Pontiac Trans-Am, etc) to be a 9-second car. There's definitely no way to put really beefy tires on the back and lower their pressure enough to carry the front wheels. (Admit it, that does look cool, even if it doesn't always help your 1/4 mile time!)

My friends and I are looking for tips in this department. I built one friend a Trans-Am dragster, and another a GNX. I myself rock a Datsun because it seemed to own the leaderboards.

We've optimized all the parts already (my Datsun is an R3/792, the Trans-Am is an R3/721 and the GNX is an R3/728). Now we're looking for tuning setups. We've played with gearing, suspension, tire pressure, etc., but we all feel woefully ill-equipped to actually know what we're doing.

Any advice on tuning setups, notably for those three cars? Yes, I know I can buy setups on the marketplace, but I'd rather actually learn something and know what I'm doing. Plus the good Datsun setups are all like 50,000 credits, and I need those credits to make sure I have cars that qualify for every race! (I still haven't done all of the events, nor have I even bothered with much of season play ... )

Comment: Getting a lot of tire spin off the line? AWD is always going to have advantage because power distribution to all wheels lessens the chance of wheel spin and increases the chance of a solid launch. I've had no luck with mucle cars in Forza 2 or 3. IMO the simulation aspects of the game need improvement.

Comment: @Dustin: Agreed re simulation aspects needing improvement. Yeah, I did the AWD conversion for my Datsun (and a whole bunch of other upgrades), but my friends and I still like the tuning aspect, and really want to learn its ins and outs. (As someone on the Forza boards has in his sig: Sell a man a tune, he races for a day. Teach a man to tune, he races forever.)

Answer (score 1):

> there really isn't much you can do, it's just inevitable that your
>   gonna spin.
>
> > stiffen up the front springs, bump damping, and rear rebound damping,
> >     soften the rear springs, bump damping, and drop the suspension with
> >     the front maybe slightly higher than the rear.this should maximize weight transfer and give you an immeasurably small increase in
> >     traction(at least, from what i've found).
>
> A player's Foxbody runs 10.5's . It's ALL about how you launch. MUST
>   run a 2 gear setup. When you launch, run it near redline, hold it
>   steady when it takes off, then go full throttle right below about 2k.

This is what I've found from looking.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a tuning database for Drag Racing in Forza 4, I don't know how much help it will be but they have a significant list of cars and the link is [here](http://forums.forzamotorsport.net/forums/thread/5458956.aspx).

> Hey guys after pitching my idea with ID TimberWolf (creater of the Drift tuning database) I have decided to start up a Drag Tuning database for the Strip, this im hoping will be a great resource to find Drag Tunes for the easy price of building the car.
>
> This Topic is about Drag tuning setups please use this thread to request setups and you can use this thread to give feed back on existing setups but please No off topic discussion here.
>
> - means that the setup is also available on the storefront if that is the case please add that info in your post as well if your setup is on the Storefront and does not have a
> - please Inform me via PM or here in the thread to add it
>
> I understand that drag tunes are kept pretty sacred within the drag racing community but i feel our community will grow if people had access to some great tunes or a good starting point on how they can setup there own cars.
>
> The list with manufactures and cars available with a tuning setup is below. click on the tune title to go directly to the posted tune. -- User #219220 @ Forzamotorsport.net forums.